# is posible different language on web socket?

Tags: java, javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

i have the problem when i want to try web socket technology on my application.
but i want to ask about requiretment of web socket.

1)  is posible i'm using Server with javascript language ex is  [socket.io](http://socket.io/#how-to-use)

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(3001);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', {hello: 'can you hear me'});
});
```

and the client using Java language example is [socket.io.java](https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client)
i'm using this method to get message from server

```
public void onMessage(JSONObject json, IOAcknowledge ack) {
                Log.d("We received a message: " , json.toString());
            }
```

with my socket server is

```
SocketIO socket = new SocketIO("http://127.0.0.1:3001/news");
```

2)  is support to all machine? or browser?i'm newbie on web socket programing, please help me

thanks for your answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can build the server in any language you want, but web sockets are not a simple socket, they are sockets that "follow" a specific protocol, so make sure you read the specification of this protocol and implement it on your server so any browser will be able to stablish a connection to it.

And you can also write a client in any language, but if you're not using javascript then I don't see why you would use web sockets instead of using just a simple socket. But if you want to, just take a look at what data a browser sends to a web socket server and emulate it from your own client.

Comment: i'm using javascript in client that is successfully test, i can send request and get response from server everytime... when i used another language in client i have stack i think my code is miss.

Comment: Probably because you're not sending the handshake data from your client, it's something that is required by the web socket protocol. When you use Javascript the browser does that for you under the hood but if you're writing your own client you have to do it yourself.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i solve my problem, i'm sending the handshake to server but i don't handle that so i can't get message from client,just give handle and i can run my program perfectly...:)

Comment: i think this link can be help another people who has been get same problem... http://groups.google.com/group/socket_io/browse_thread/thread/21f993b77d98c928?fwc=1

Comment: In short, websockets provide an additional network layer over HTTP.  The advantage to using websockets over a normal socket for a client (and hence not necessarily javascript) is that you can bypass many standard proxies and firewalls by interleaving normal HTTP traffic with websocket traffic to create the appearance of a normal socket to both applications.  I've now built a couple of these by wrapping the standard port-to-port traffic of an old application around a websocket proxy layer at both ends and apache2-mod-wstunnel to avoid the need for an extra port. :-)

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on Delta's answer, "websockets" is a variation of the HTTP protocol where the client sends an HTTP request message, the server sends an HTTP response, and then the client and server use the still-open TCP/IP connection to do "other things".  The request and response contain special headers which allow the client and server to agree to use the connection in this way.

In order for this to work, the client and server both need to understand at least a subset of the HTTP protocol in order to do the initial "handshake".  Hence you *can't* simply use a websocket client to talk to a plain socket server ... or vice versa.  (If you try to do that, both ends will see unexpected stuff / protocol errors.  And the websocket end *should* promptly close its end of the TCP/IP connection.)

Having said that, a websocket client and a websocket server can be implemented in just about any modern programming language.  (And the same goes for plain socket clients and servers.)

Comment: WebSockets is not a variation of HTTP. It has an HTTP friendly initial handshake but after that it's more like raw sockets (full duplex, bi-directional, persistent). The HTTP friendly handshake makes it easy to run a WebSocket server and web server on the same port (80, 443) which allows it to work with existing firewall configuration.

Answer (score -3):

[Sockets](http://linux.die.net/man/7/socket) are an operating system thing. You can use them with any language providing the relevant interface or glue code to the operating [system calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) implementing them (e.g. on Linux: [socket(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/socket), [connect(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/connect), [accept(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/accept), [listen(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/listen), [poll(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll), [recv(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recv) etc...)

But if you are newbie about sockets, I strongly suggest reading a good [network programming](http://www.unpbook.com/) book.

Comment: websockets are not the same as regular sockets